# Having difficulties with JQuery clone()

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu, clone

You can see what I am ***trying*** to do in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pV6x5/16/

The original set of three dropdowns are using javascript to generate what options are available in the second and third dropdowns based on the selected value of the first.

When this is cloned and you select an option in the first drop-down of the clone, it is the 2nd and third dropdowns of the original that change and I don't know how to fix this :S

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Martin

**UPDATE**
After some reading, I have changed the id's to just use classes in order to try and avoid any clashes: http://jsfiddle.net/QbfXq/1/

Unfortunately it seems to still behave exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there I did some modifications in your code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QbfXq/2/). I only did modify the first 4 or 5 options, you'll have to modify the remaining code yourself.

The major problem is that when you clone, the class and name remain the same for each element.
Then you only initialized values and operand object one time in (`$(document).ready`), so that's why you kept modifying the same element.
In my code, I did look for the next element of the clicked arg.
But I think you should organize a little bit more your code, using `<div>` for examples would allow you to be more precise using the request.
Instead of using `next` you could use a search in div children for example.

Well I hope you see the way it should work.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

The only thing I am confused about is why you switch between  `$(this).next`, `$(this).children` and `$(this).find`?

Not all of the values are filled in but the `colour` option seems to break it and so do some others but I don't understand why. If you could just explain a little it would help a lot.

Comment: as I told you I did try some things, forget the `children` as your hierarchy isn't fitted to. Same goes for the `find`. As you put elements on next to the other, `next` should do the trick

Comment: ok, thank you very much. do you have any suggestions on a better way to structure the code that determines which values to show?

Comment: I would put every Arg/Operand/value in a reference div. Then I would clone the div and modify the id of the clone. Once you have done that you can use `.children([selector})` to ensure to take the direct descendants.